How can I pass data into a LWC custom property editor dynamically?
Background
I am trying to get a piece of information, (the name of the current page's object in this case) into a custom property editor instance.
The only way I've been able to get data into it is through the value, and I know that I can shove multiple things through by using a JSON string, because that is what SF does in some built in components.
However, what I haven't been able to figure out is how to dynamically inject data. I don't want to send in objectApiName, I want to send in "OrderSummary", (so that I can use it to filter a combobox of fields).
I've found some other articles talking about how public properties should be treated as read-only but aren't anymore as of 2021. But I'm at a loss of how to proceed.
Code
XML Property Definitions:
<property name="binding" type="lightning__textType" label="Field Name" editor="c/fdseObjectFieldBinding" />

Question
What is the official way of pushing data from a component into a custom property editor programmatically?

the title and your question seem to be contradicting to me. Are you looking for a way, to pass in value from Salesforce UI into LWC (For example: When placing LWC component on a recordPage via "Edit Page", you would want to pass in some own custom properties along)? And where is this LWC going to be placed, recordPage?

The answer is that this isn't possible, outside of using a messaging service. In my case, I just had to make multiple CPEs and add the data I wanted to pass in to the property default value.

If you are looking to pass in value from Salesforce UI (Lightning Record Page Edit UI?) I am not very sure what the UI is called, but basically I am referring to the UI you get when you edit the lightning recordPage. 
I am also assuming that you are placing this Lightning Web Component (LWC), on a recordPage. 
Here's an example of passing property value from Salesforce to LWC. The property here is called "valueFromPage".
Here's how my XML would look like: (documentation link)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property type="String" name="valueFromPage"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>

JavaScript
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class PassingPropertyFromPageToLWC extends LightningElement {
    @api valueFromPage;

    connectedCallback(){
        console.log('connectedCallback()');
        console.log('valueFromPage => ', this.valueFromPage);
    }
    
    renderedCallback(){
        console.log('renderedCallback()');
        console.log('valueFromPage => ', this.valueFromPage);
    }
}

HTML
<template>
    {valueFromPage}
</template>

Full code can also be found here, where you can deploy and test it out of this is what you are looking for.
Also Special thanks to the documentation you linked.

Hi there! That won't work for what I'm looking for. If you are in Experience Builder, you can pass in the current record and current object name by using the special {!recordId} and {!objectApiName} syntax. You set those as the value of the object property through the property editor, and within the component itself, they'll be changed to the real values. However, you can't actually pass data into a component's customer property editor instance, it looks like. Basically, my CPE contains a combobox of field options, and I want to load them dynamically based on the current object.

In your code, you aren't passing a value into a CPE, but just into the main component itself. I need either the page or the component to get the value into the CPE.

@Kelderic I see, din't know this was specific to Experience Builder/CPE, perhaps you could edit your question to provide more context, maybe someone with relevant experience would help :)

I just went ahead and answered. Answer being, it's not possible. You can't update a component's property values from inside said component. And all LWC components, in Experience Builder, and completely isolated outside of the values being passed by the framework.
